# Drupal Shipping Rules with Product Option Sets

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce, commerce, drupal-rules

I have an pricing attribute option set up on one of the Drupal products.
I am trying to create shipping rules that address:

1) Which of the options for the product the user selected
2) Where the user's address is

To calculate individual shipping rates. So, for example, I might have someone order the two year subscription to Japan and need to have a shipping rule for that price. Then I need another if someone orders a one year subscription to the US.

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far ? what went wrong ? how do you expect people to help you with such a question (which sounds more like a feature request...). Basically you need a set of rules which test if a particular product is in cart, if it has a particular property (chosen by the customer), and test the shipping informations filled by the customer. Start here maybe : https://commerceguys.com/blog/introduction-commerce-shipping-screencast